# Get css top value as number not as string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In jQuery you can get the top position relative to the parent as a number, but you can not  get the css top value as a number if it was set in `px`.
Say I have the following:

```
#elem{
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
 }
```

```
<div>
  Bla text bla this takes op vertical space....
  <div id='elem'>bla</div>
</div>
```

```
$('#elem').position().top; //Returns the number (10+(the vertical space took by the text))
$('#elem').css('top'); //Returns the string '10px'
```

But I want to have the css top property as the number `10`.
How would one achieve this?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You can use the parseInt() function to convert the string to a number, e.g:

```
parseInt($('#elem').css('top'));
```

**Update:** (as suggested by Ben): You should give the radix too:

```
parseInt($('#elem').css('top'), 10);
```

Forces it to be parsed as a decimal number, otherwise strings beginning with '0' might be parsed as an octal number (might depend on the browser used).

Comment: You should give the radix too:

parseInt($('#elem').css('top'), 10);

Forces it to be parsed as base 10, otherwise strings beginning with '0' will be parsed in base 8.

Comment: It's could be a float though, so it's better to use parseFloat.

Answer (score 24):

A jQuery plugin based on M4N's answer

```
jQuery.fn.cssNumber = function(prop){
    var v = parseInt(this.css(prop),10);
    return isNaN(v) ? 0 : v;
};
```

So then you just use this method to get number values

```
$("#logo").cssNumber("top")
```

Answer (score 14):

A slightly more practical/efficient plugin based on Ivan Castellanos' answer (which was based on M4N's answer). Using `|| 0` will convert Nan to 0 without the testing step.

I've also provided float and int variations to suit the intended use:

```
jQuery.fn.cssInt = function (prop) {
    return parseInt(this.css(prop), 10) || 0;
};

jQuery.fn.cssFloat = function (prop) {
    return parseFloat(this.css(prop)) || 0;
};
```

### Usage:

```
$('#elem').cssInt('top');    // e.g. returns 123 as an int
$('#elem').cssFloat('top');  // e.g. Returns 123.45 as a float
```

### Test fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/E5LTu/

Comment: It would seem that one should either always use the cssFloat or consider that cssInt will strip a value like 25.9999999px to 25.

Comment: @justingordon: That is the correct integer truncation behaviour for an int, so it really comes down to the required usage of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Its not work for me ,also i got the Top as String and remove the Pixel

```js
let item = document.querySelector('.myclass');

let IngTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(item).top.replace('px',''));
```

```css
.myclass{
top : 150px
}
```

```html
<div class='myclass'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) as follows:

```
const pxStyles = {
    get(target, prop) {
        let val = target.style[prop];
        if (!val.endsWith('px')) {
            throw Exception(`style.${prop}: doesn't have a pixel value: ${val}`)
        }
        return parseFloat(val.substring(0, val.length - 2));
    },
    set(target, prop, value) {
        target.style[prop] = value + 'px';
        return true;
    }
}

const elem_px = new Proxy(document.getElementById('elem'), pxStyles);
elem_px.top += 1234;
```