# Moving css position using increment

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to move an elements position from its current position using jQuery and css. However, the syntax I'm using doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
var ball = $("#ball1");
var movement = {
    x: 5,
    y: 5
}
ball.css({
    top: "+="+movement.y,  //+= adds the value
    left: "+="+movement.x
});
```

Can anybody confirm if my code under `ball.css({` is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not correct. You gave to use something like this

```
ball.css({
    top: parseInt(ball.css('top')) + movement.y + 'px',
    left: parseInt(ball.css('left')) + movement.x + 'px'
});
```

> Get the computed style properties for the first element in the set of matched elements.

As you can see on the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1) website, `jQuery.css` will give us the computed value, meaning that we don't get `15` if the `left` value is `15px`, for example. For that, we have to use `parseInt`. Check this answer for more nice usages of [`parseInt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395163/get-css-top-value-as-number-not-as-string). So this should the its job, but as  someone answered on that post, we can create a jQuery plugin to make it look nicer:

```
jQuery.fn.cssNumber = function(prop){
    var v = parseInt(this.css(prop), 10);
    return isNaN(v) ? 0 : v;
};

ball.css({
    top: ball.cssNumber('top') + movement.y + 'px',
    left: ball.cssNumber('left') + movement.x + 'px'
});
```

I have also created a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/1dggkz9u/1/) for you.

Comment: I've tried reading the Jquery.fn documentation but I don't completely understand it. Does it override the `cssNumber` or make a new function called `cssNumber`?

Comment: For a better understanding of that, you should read about [jQuery Plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
ball.css({
    top: +movement.y,
    left: +movement.x
});
```

Comment: This seems to move it, then it goes back to its original position

Comment: @MarksCode can you put your code in a fiddle for easy understand?

Comment: Yea here you go, thanks for the help :) https://jsfiddle.net/vo1zysds/ There is a "BlueBall.png" on my local machine though so it won't show up in the fiddle

Comment: It doesn't move for me.